# It is posible show part of div (html element) in other container side horizontal, using css/jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

It is posible to do such a trick, like in the image, using css/jquery or other methods ? I need that the same elemnt's one part would be in the right side and the other part in the left side :)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/a320ffs.jpg/

Comment: Wow that's a confusing question... Mind explaining a little more?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your best bet would be to use Javascript to compute the width of the first div and use that width as the background-position horizontal offset for the second div.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to calculate if any part of the div is outside of the boundaries of the container. The container would have its overflow-property set to hidden by css.

Then you would use javaScript/jQuery to clone the div that is partly outside of the container and place it in a negative left position, equal to the number of pixels that you calculated in the first step.

This is the concept I would use, hope it helps.

Comment: Good idea. But all of these small (colorfull) containers are movable (draggable), so i need to do calculations on darag event. It is HUGE script :)

Comment: Yes you will have to make the calculations in the drag script, I don't think it would be that much of a performance hit. The drag script already knows where to put the div, then just do if(div.x + div.width > container.x + container.width). If that is the case do the cloning and position of the new div, this should not make the script a lot more complicated

Comment: OK, but if I clone the object it means it will be a dublicate, and if then i will move the cloned object, the parent object will not move :( So it's bad for me to do a clone :(

Comment: Okay i agree it will be a bit of a hassle to implement. I was just trying to help with the actual positioning of the div in relation to it's container. The question was actually just about the positioning. If you need additional help with the code I suggest you brake the issues down into smaller questions which can have a more direct answer. I don't want to sound off putting but I think you will get a lot more help from more users if you split up your problem into smaller bit with a more defined problem